# Variables as a part of calling a method in python

Tags: python, function

I'm pretty new to programming and I'm creating a python game for my little sister.

I'm having trouble, because I want the variable value to be a part of the method name
Is there any way this is possible?

```
def play_with_toy(self):
    toy = gui.buttonbox(
        msg = 'Choose a toy for your potato head to play with:',
        title = 'Choose a Toy',
        choices = self.toys)
    method_name = 'play_' + toy + '()'
    myPotatoHead.method_name
```

Using Python 2.5.4 for Mac (IDLE) and easygui 0.83

Thanks for any help

Comment: The answers you've gotten are correct.  There may be better ways to design your game than what you are currently doing.  I suggest you step back after you're finished and think about what worked well and what didn't and how the way you coded things makes it easier or harder to add things in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
method = getattr(myPotatoHead, 'play_' + toy)
method()
```

Comment: If you don't need to reuse the variable method, you don't have to save the result of getattr(), and you can directly do getattrt()().

Answer (score 1):

```
getattr(myPotatoHead,"play_"+toy)()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
method = getAttr(myPotatoHead, 'play_' + toy)
method()
```

(sorry about the semi-colons! I was programming in javascript all day).